# WPF Binding - Default value for empty string

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

Is there a standard way to set a default or fallback value for a WPF binding if the bound string is empty?

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, FallbackValue='Unnamed'" />
```

The `FallbackValue` only seems to kick in when `Name` is null, but not when it is set to `String.Empty`.

Comment: there is a much simple answer at
[enter link description here][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612622/give-textblock-default-value-if-result-returns-null

Comment: there is a much simple solution at

[TextBox Default Value if Binding returns null][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612622/give-textblock-default-value-if-result-returns-null

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I was under the impression that [FallbackValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue.aspx) provides a value when the binding fails and [TargetNullValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue.aspx) provides a value when the bound value is null.

To do what you want you will either need a converter (possibly with a parameter) to convert an empty string to a target value, or put the logic in your view model.

I would probably go with a converter something like this (not tested).

```
public class EmptyStringConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{  
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
                          object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string) ? parameter : value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
                              object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 82):

`DataTrigger` is the way i do it like this:

```
<TextBox>
  <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"  BasedOn="{StaticResource ReadOnlyTextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Name.Length, FallbackValue=0, TargetNullValue=0}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{x:Static local:ApplicationLabels.NoValueMessage}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: I like this approach because it let's me bind the default value to another property in my ViewModel. Thanks :)

Comment: you can probably also do `Name` and empty string instead of `Name.length`, totally love this approach :)

Comment: Seeing as `Name` is generally a `string`, then `Name.Length` would be of type `Int32`. For this reason, there is no need specify `TargetNullValue` because the the expression will never evaluate to `null`, granted it evaluates at all. `FallbackValue` is the property pulling the weight here.

Comment: ugly way to do this... should be 1 liner for such a simple thing.

Answer (score 10):

You should create a converter for this, which implements `IValueConverter`

```
public class StringEmptyConverter : IValueConverter {

public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
      return string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)value) ? parameter : value;
    }

public object ConvertBack(
      object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
      throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

}
```

Then in xaml you'd just provide the converter to the binding, (`xxx` just represents your `Window` / `UserControl` / `Style` ... where the binding is)

```
<xxx.Resources>
<local:StringEmptyConverter x:Key="StringEmptyConverter" />
</xxx.Resources>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource StringEmptyConverter}, ConverterParameter='Placeholder Text'}" />
```

Comment: I need to specify a different default string for every binding, but I could pass in the string as the ConverterParameter.

Comment: @Viv Why binding to Name property, not to Text?

Comment: @Andrzej huh Name is the property the OP had mentioned in his question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a converter and do the respective validation on it.

```
Binding="{Binding Path=Name, Converter={StaticResource nameToOtherNameConverter}}"
```

and in your converter

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
        { /*do something and return your new value*/ }
```