# How to set a default source for an Image if binding source is null?

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm using binding for source of an `Image` control.

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageUri}"/>
```

But this `ImageUri` can be null, therefor I want to use a default image, a place holder, for that, which can be in `/Assets/PlaceHolder.png` for example.

How can I set a default image? thanks.
*(It's a WP8 app, but should not be different of WPF)*

Answer (score 35):

You can achieve it by setting `TargetNullValue`

```
<Image>
    <Image.Source>
        <Binding Path="ImageUri" >
            <Binding.TargetNullValue>
                <ImageSource>/Assets/PlaceHolder.png</ImageSource>
            </Binding.TargetNullValue>
        </Binding>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Comment: I have an application where it loads hundreds of images. How to show a default image until the actual image is loaded?

Comment: @ArjunKR you might want to visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19113141/is-it-possible-to-show-default-image-before-original-load-from-server

Comment: Brilliant! WPF never ceases to amaze me with its veering from simple elegance to frustrating verbosity.

Comment: Just to add in case it is not obvious, the "ImageUri" is a binding path to the Image control's data context's property "ImageUri" and can be changed to the appropriate path -- it's not part of ImageSource. 
I also had to specify my ImageSource as an assembly uri for it to work: `/AssemblyName;component/Images/Placeholder.png`

Answer (score 4):

You can actually go the other way around which is a better experience in my opinion by simply using two `Image` controls in a `Grid` layout, one with the local placeholder source and one with the remote `Binding`. The local image is already there when you your remote binding is null. However if the binding is not null, it automatically covers the local placeholder image once it gets rendered.

```cs
<Grid>
    <Image Source="Assets/Placeholder.png"/>
    <Image Source="{Binding ImageUri}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This works in theory but my images have transparent backgrounds. That means that I can see the image below my other image. How can I hide the image underneath?

Comment: @Sweepster Try using the ImageOpened event of the bound image. Set the opacity of the placeholder image to 0 if the image opened event of the data bound event gets successfully triggered!!

Answer (score 3):

You can set the ImageFailed event on your image,

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageUri}" ImageFailed="Image_ImageFailed"/>
```

and use the following C# to load a specific image in its place.

```
private void Image_ImageFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((Image)sender).Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/MyDefaultImage.png", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

```
<Image>
    <Image.Source>
        <Binding Path="ImageUri">
            <Binding.TargetNullValue>
                <BitmapImage UriSource="/ProjName;component/Assets/PlaceHolder.png" />                    
            </Binding.TargetNullValue>
        </Binding>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **ImageFailed** event and **ChangePropertyAction**.

This Code Snippet worked for me:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"

<Image x:Name="GeologyMapsLegend" Stretch="Fill" Height="150">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="ImageFailed">
            <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Source" TargetName="GeologyMapsLegend">
                <ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                    <ImageSource>
                        /LanSysWebGIS;component/Pictures/Icon/NoImageAvailable.jpg
                    </ImageSource>
                </ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
            </ei:ChangePropertyAction>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Image>
```

Comment: I have an application where it loads hundreds of images. How to show a default image until the actual image is loaded?

Answer (score 1):

use `TargetNullValue` attribute. It is very helpful if I don't want to display any image.

Answer (score -2):

You should try to play with `FallBackValue` here. These two links should provide more help

[WPF Binding - Default value for empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567588/wpf-binding-default-value-for-empty-string)

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue.aspx)