# Is it possible to show default image before original load from server?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I want to show default image (some thing like brand icon) before original image is loaded from server. It is possible with out writing much code. Because I want same behavior in whole app.

or we need to create custom control for that. Please guide me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to reuse it at a lot of different place it's probably easier to just create a CustomControl. 
Here is a small user control which should do that:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PhoneApp1.ImageWithLoading"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="480"
             x:Name="myImageWithLoading">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
        <Image x:Name="temporaryImage"  Source="/Assets/Loading"/>
        <Image Source="{Binding Source,ElementName=myImageWithLoading}" ImageOpened="RemoteImage_OnLoaded"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>



public partial class ImageWithLoading : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Source", typeof (ImageSource), typeof (ImageWithLoading), new PropertyMetadata(default(ImageSource)));

    public ImageSource Source
    {
        get { return (ImageSource) GetValue(SourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SourceProperty, value); }
    }
    public ImageWithLoading()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void RemoteImage_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        temporaryImage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked perfectly for me. I am try same thing for `ImageBrush`. I have one **Ellipse**. In `Ellipse.Fill` property I have added ImageBrush. How can I use your code for `ImageBrush`?

Answer (score 2):

Another option might be to create a default style for Images in your default style page like so

```
<Style TargetType="Image">
     <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Assets/Load.jpg"/>
</Style>
```

and just set the source when the image is ready