# Display a default image if ImageSource's URL generates a HTTP 404

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, http

Is it possible to set a default image for WPF's Image-Control?

```
<Image Source={Binding Path=ImageUrl, IsAsync=True}" />
```

Eg. if `ImageUrl` causes a HTTP 404 response, I would like to have a default/placeholder image to be displayed.

Comment: Check this:http://stackoverflow.com/a/19027808/

Comment: My apologies.  I misunderstood.

Comment: Just set a FallbackValue

Comment: @ChrisW. FallbackValue won't help, because the binding produces a valid value (an image URI). It's the subsequent built-in conversion from string to ImageSource that fails.

Comment: As an alternative to the solution linked in the comment by Bolu, you may implement a binding converter that performs the download and handles possible errors.

Comment: the image will be inside a ItemsControl or alone? depending the case I can give you an answer

Comment: @Clemens: that was my first thought also. But how do I Implement the async handling (IsAsync=true)?

Comment: @JuanPabloGarciaCoello: its used alone, not within an ItemsControl.

Comment: @user1130329 That would be difficult, because the converter is always called synchronously (i.e. in the UI thread). I'd suggest to add an ImageFailed handler.