# How to deal with the two way binding error for TextBox?

Tags: wpf, binding

The logic is two way bind Textbox's `Text` in the viewModel and to implement some function based on the `Text` change in the viewModel. 
But when deleting all the text, there is a data binding error and the following functions depending on the `Text` change never begin. `Text` is bind to an int value. It looks like when binding fails`imageQuantity = value`, the following codes did not get called. Any ideas how to work around this?

```
public int ImageQuantity
{
    get { return imageQuantity; }
    set
    {
        imageQuantity = value;
        if (ImageQuantity > 0)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(LastSymbol))
            {
                ImageAmount = ImageQuantity * (QQ.Ask + QQ.Bid) * 0.5;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged(() => this.ImageQuantity);
        }
        else
        {
            ImageAmount = 0.0;
        }  
    }
```

Edit:One way to fix this is to go back to implement `TextChanged`event Command with prism.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567588/wpf-binding-default-value-for-empty-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ImageQuantity` property setter will not be called when the user deletes all of the text in the data bound `TextBox` because your `ImageQuantity` property is an `int` and an empty `string` cannot be converted into an `int`. There is a simple solution to get around this.

If you need to call the code in your setter even if the input is invalid (such as an empty `string`), you could change your `ImageQuantity` property into a `string` and do your own conversion to `int` in the property setter (obviously with a `try` check):

```
public string ImageQuantity
{
    get { return imageQuantity; }
    set
    {
        int intValue = 0;
        if (int.TryParse(value, out intValue))
        {
            // value is a valid integer
            imageQuantity = value;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(LastSymbol))
            {
                ImageAmount = ImageQuantity * (QQ.Ask + QQ.Bid) * 0.5;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged(() => this.ImageQuantity);
        }
        else // value is a NOT a valid integer
        {
            ImageAmount = 0.0;
        }  
    }
}
```